# virtuemart product detail page sef urls

Tags: joomla-3.x, virtuemart, sef

Im using:

joomla36 -
virtuemart 3.0.16 -
sj-market template made by www.smartaddons.com

...

in my template there is a module that shows 6 products in a row in the front page.

the module has 4 tabs, each for a category.

when i click on a product on default loaded tab, it goes to product details page and its url is sef :/

when i click on another tab, 6 product loads form the category the tab points to.

when i click on one of the loaded products, it goes to the product detail page, but using not sef url

anyone has any idea about this?

mysite: www.farafan-market.ir

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that issue on your site. I would suggest contacting template vendor smartaddons.com with your support request, because this incorrect behavior is definitely up to their module as a part of SJ Market template.

Comment: I have just checked their SJ-Market Demo at http://demo.smartaddons.com/templates/joomla3/sj-market/index.php/en/ . The very same behavior is shown in the tabs of homepage modules 'Best Sellers' and 'New Arrivals'. So, it's their bug...

Comment: yeah.. but they're not gonna support becuz my membership is over. so I've got to solve it myself :/

Comment: :-( I've had a such feeling... If I find their quickstart somewhere, I'll take a look at that module, but don't hold me to it... Being very busy lately...

Comment: it would be veeery nice of you.. :)   meanwhile ill work on it

Comment: I have found that module from template (mod_sj_vm_ajax_tabs) and have found the reason for the bug: System SEF plugin is not applied to ajax output in other tabs than preloaded one, so that is why preloaded tab shows correct URLs, because for whole page event `onAfterRender` triggers System SEF plugin, but for AJAX-ized tabs it doesn't. But I don't know how to fix it, sorry. I dont know how to call system_sef plugin and apply it to output `$ajax_respond` on line 36 in file `/modules/mod_sj_vm_ajax_tabs/mod_sj_vm_ajax_tabs.php`. Sorry again.

Comment: oh.. that OK.. thanks for spending time on it :) ..  for now i added "http://www.farafan-market.ir/index.php/" to the beginning of the link ($item->link), to make the product page display in a separated page.